# Understanding enum's static members initialization

Tags: java, constructor, enums

Bloch's Effective Java said this:

> Enum constructors aren’t permitted to access the enum’s static fields,
>   except for compile-time constant fields. This restriction is necessary
>   because these **static fields have not yet been initialized when the**
>   **constructors run**.

To me, it's not clear because here's what JLS's talking:

[JLS 8.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7):

> A static initializer declared in a class is executed when the class **is**
>   **initialized**

So, all static members are being initialized before any constructor's invokation has been started. What did I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The enum's constants are themselves initialized by calling the constructor. This means the constructor cannot access the constant since it's not yet created at that time.

In other words, say you have:

```
enum MyEnum {

   FOO, BAR;

   private MyEnum() {
        // Illegal
        // FOO already calls this constructor
        System.out.println(FOO);
   }

}
```

`FOO` and `BAR` are equivalent to:

```
public static final MyEnum foo;
public static final MyEnum bar;
```

When the enum class is loaded by the JVM, `FOO` and `BAR` are created by calling the enum private constructor, something like:

```
foo = MyEnum(); // name of enum, the params are not relevant
bar = MyEnum();
```

So Java does not allow you to access that field in the constructor since it is still under creation. You can run the following to verify:

```
enum MyEnum {
    FOO, BAR;

    private MyEnum() {
        System.out.println("Initializing");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(MyEnum.FOO);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Initializing
Initializing
FOO
```

"Initializing" is printed twice, one by the creation of `FOO` and one by `BAR`.

The JLS also says this about enums:

> It is a compile-time error to reference a `static` field of an enum type from constructors, instance initializers, or instance variable initializer expressions of the enum type, unless the field is a constant variable (§4.12.4).

Comment: The rule is not quite clear. Couldn't you give a little bit better explanation than "The standard say so"? :)To create the instance of some class we must initialize it first. I think, enums are not an exception, so when JVM starts creating the instances of  the enum, the enum's already initialized. So, the static initializer's already been executed, which means we can access it from the constructor safely.